# Java Generic Class

Tags: java

```java
public interface EXPeekableQueue<E extends Comparable<E>>{
     public void enqueue(E e);
}

public interface EXammutableQueue<E>{
   public EXammutableQueue<E> enqueue(E e);
   public E peek();
}
```

What exactly does this Syntax mean?
I am  having trouble understanding Java Generic classes. Can someone send me a link to a good tutorial or pdf file?
Thank you!!

Comment: Once you have read the basic concepts from Oracle java tutorials, [Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html#SECTION1) will give you some more insight.

Comment: Google Java Generics and get understanding of it first.

Answer (score 3):

There is no other place better than Oracle java tutorials to learn java features, here you go:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 0):

I've always found this site to be useful: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Topic1.

Regarding your code, it looks like there's one too many closing angled brackets in the first line. Is there more?

Answer (score 0):

The second one is easier.  When implementing this interface, you need to instantiate with a concrete element class, say, MyElementClass.  Then you need to provide the two methods with E replaced with MyElementClass.

```
class My implements EXammutableQueue<MyElement>{
```

.....

```
public EXammutableQueue<MyElement> enqueue(MyElement e){
......
}

public MyElement peek(){...}

....
}
```

Now you can do the same for the first one, which, in addition, requires E is a member of comparable with itself.